# Create new file from contextual menu

Tags: finder, shortcut-menu

Is there a program I can download to add an option to create a new file to the contextual menu of finder? [NuFile](http://growlichat.com/NuFile.php) doesn't seem to work in Snow Leopard.

Comment: you just need to add to finder or if suggest you equivalent to finder it's ok too?

Comment: Adding to finder is preferable

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are happy using a toolbar button instead of the contextual menu, you can use [New Text File Here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-To-Create-New-Text-File-in-Finder-140373.shtml) from Jonas Wisser. Just drop it into Finder's toolbar.

Note: As of OS X 10.11.4 this program no longer seems to be working.

Answer (score 4):

[Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) also adds a contextual option for creating new files, but it's shareware.  Lots of other cool feature though.

Answer (score 1):

[New File Applescript with Toolbar Icon](https://github.com/RomanSmolka/finder-new-file)

Found this open source gem. Can either use the .App or add the Applescript manually. Will add a New File widget to the Finder toolbar.

[image: New File Toolbar Icon]

Answer (score 0):

This also works pretty well if you're willing to spend a bit of money:
https://langui.net/new-file-menu/